# PHP-AJAX call in the same php file-duplicated page

Tags: php, ajax, request

when I use the ajax call indicated below, my page is seen 2 times. I think the ajax function calls my page again to view the return result.

```
<?
if(isset($_GET['q'])){
$q=(int)$_GET['q'];
echo $q;
}
?>
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function showUser(str)
 {
 if (str=="")
   {
   document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
   return;
   } 
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
     document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
   }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","java.php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<form>
 <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
 <option value="">Select a person:</option>
 <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
 <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
 <option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
 <option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
 </select>
 </form>
 </br><div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

 </body>
</html>
```

but I only want to use the parameter q in my php mixed html file. for example, with ajax I catch the value of person and put it in q parameter, then use it in an sql query for example(I'll use that query to fill another dropdown list)

```
"select * from persons where id=".$q;
```

how can i do that without duplicating the page?

*i cannot put images bc of being rookie

Comment: What is duplicated in your page? The whole page is shown again in `txtHint`? Is this page java.php? If not, what should java.php render?

Comment: the whole page. under echo, the selection dropdown list repeates. but selection value in the second list effects the echo lies above.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this code belongs to `java.php`

and yes, your ajax is also calling `java.php`file with `q` parameter.

You can do two things.

- Either you can change the file you are calling and do whatever necessary there, say `ajaxresult.php`
- or you can stop the code when it is called with ajax

  ```
  if(isset($_GET['q'])) {

      $q=(int)$_GET['q'];
      echo $q;
      exit;
   }
  ```

Comment: and how can i store returned value to another parameter or usable parameter in php in java.php? i parse the code with java.php and ajax.php. ajax.php includes echo $q result but i want to use q as a parameter in java.php. is there a solution?

Comment: If you just need to change some dropdownlists you could do it using jQuery or another ajax, without reloading the page again. You can load page once, and change dropdownlists using jQuery

Comment: i'll go on with exploring jQuery then. thank you for all replies.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to have everything in 1 file? 
I believe it is named java.php - you are calling it with ajax, first condition will echo q, but your html code will get printed too, because there is no else. Add else, or place php called by ajax to different file.

Edit: you can use someting like this

```
<?php 
if ( 1==1) // or 1!=1
{
?>
text
<?
}
else
{
?>
someothertext
<?
}
```

EDIT: Tested, 100% working - depending on condition writes only `text` or `someothertext`, so it should work for you too, is it still printing whole page?